# I'm not able to pass my ip-address as an input to my database in mysql usnig c#

Tags: c#, mysql

i'm not able to pass my ip address as an input to my database in mysql using c# 
my code:

```
string Query = ("SELECT mobile FROM UserDetails where machine_ip=" +ipaddress);
```

It works fine if the is a string that looks like this: "1234567890"
but doesn work if it looks like this: "127.0.0.0"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
"SELECT mobile FROM UserDetails where machine_ip = '" + ipaddress + "'"
```

Also, you should consider using parametrized queries to avoid a SQL injection vulnerability, if this is end-user-facing code.

Answer (score 3):

Don't you need to put strings into quotes in the SQL String... Or better yet, use a parameterised query (that way you'll help defend yourself against a SQL Injection Attack)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the makeup of your database, it is likely that `machine_ip` is not `VARCHAR`. Which is why a number works, but IP address with "ASCII", does not.

Answer (score 1):

Add it into Apostrophes

```
string Query = ("SELECT mobile FROM UserDetails where machine_ip='" +ipaddress+ "'");
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you should enclose ipaddress with '
like this:

```
"SELECT mobile FROM UserDetails where machine_ip='" + ipaddress + "'"
```

Answer (score 1):

If in data base you store the ip address without dots like 127001 you should remove the dots from your input string IP

```
string res = inputId.Replace(".","");
```

and don't use the string concatenation in you SQL statement use parametrized query

Comment: Sooo... what if someone has the IP 192.168.11.1, and someone else has 192.168.1.11? ;)

Answer (score 1):

`127.0.0.0` can not be converted to a string implicitly, so you have to call it like this:

```
("SELECT mobile FROM UserDetails where machine_ip='" + ipaddress + "'");
```

Oh, and please beware of [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to store IP addresses in a database, a right way and a wrong way.

The right way is to convert the IP addresses to a base-10 integer - 127.0.0.1 turns into 2130706433 and 192.168.10.10 turns into 3232238090.

The wrong way is to store the values with the periods in them as strings.

If the person storing IPs used the right way, then you just need to wrap up your IP addresses in INET_ATON calls in your query, like so:

```
SELECT mobile FROM UserDetails where machine_ip=INET_ATON('127.0.0.1');
```

If the IP addresses in the table are stored as strings, you'll just need to enclose your address in single-quotes and everything should work fine (though less efficiently).

```
SELECT mobile FROM UserDetails where machine_ip='127.0.0.1';
```